# Typescript: Why/how is the return type of a user-defined "Type Guard" better than returning a boolean?

Tags: typescript, typeguards

From [this tutorial](https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/typescript-type-guards/): A user-defined type guard function is a function that returns "arg is aType". For example:

```
function isCustomer(partner: any): partner is Customer {
    return partner instanceof Customer;
}
```

```
function signContract(partner: BusinessPartner): string {
    let message: string;
    if (isCustomer(partner)) {
        message = partner.isCreditAllowed() ? 'Sign a new contract with the customer' : 'Credit issue';
    } else {
        message = partner.isInShortList() ? 'Sign a new contract with the supplier' : 'Need to evaluate further';
    }

    return message;
}
```

Why is the return type of 'partner is Customer' advantageous over simply returning a boolean?

Comment: It *is* simply returning a boolean. The difference is that a type guard tells TS to treat that boolean as the argument being a given type or not. Otherwise TS wouldn't guess that a random boolean result has such an implication.https://tsplay.dev/NDyjjm

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The difference is clear now. I am discovering all sorts of new syntax with Typescript :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
        message = partner.isCreditAllowed() ? 'Sign a new contract with the customer' : 'Credit issue';
```

is the point of the tutorial.

Normally you would have to cast `partner` to type `Customer` before calling `isCreditAllowed`. But because you have a Type Guard on the `isCustomer` return type, TypeScript can dispense with the need for a cast.

Expressions like `typeof A === B` carry these guards implicitly. But by replacing that condition with a function call, you have to "put that information back" into the expression by making the claim in the return type of `isCustomer`. `boolean` alone would not be enough for the compiler.